# WP posts using index.php instead of single.php

Tags: posts, permalinks, single

The posts on my custom theme are using the `index.php` file instead of `single.php`  _ I have looked through at least 10 questions on SO_ although many of them are very old _

Some answers said that if the WP loop isn't set up in `single.php` then it won't be called _ BUT my single.php file does contain the loop _

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container fadeIn" id="perimeter">
        <section id="page">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="divPad">
                        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php echo wpautop('Sorry, no posts were found'); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>                    
                    </div>
                </div>       
           </div>
        </section>

        <div class="horizBuffer2"></div>
    </div><!-- /#perimeter -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

One answer appears on several questions and judging from the spelling and other idiosyncrasies has clearly been copy/pasted _ It says something about changing permalinks in the WP dashboard Settings section _ but it doesn't explain clearly what should be changed _

IMPORTANT: This custom theme does NOT have a blogroll page _ All posts are sent to different pages via their categories _

Thanks in advance to anyone who can get my posts to display on `single.php`

Comment: Are you sure that the template being used is indeed `index.php` ?

Comment: hi Sally _ very happy to see you cos you helped me out once before with with a bootstrap 4 modal : )

Comment: this is the URL to a post which I want to show up in the single.php so that I can style the page >>> https://lilyrigby.com/index.php/2019/08/12/hughie-odonoghue/

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad to see you've got it sorted already. :)

Comment: Good to see you again @SallyCJ _ thanks for showing up : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`single.php` will only display a single post on the other hand `index.php` is the default template that displays everything including `posts`, `post`, `page`, `categories`, and `tags` only if specific template file is not present.

Comment: thanks for your reply @DenIsahac _ I only want a single post to be displayed _ from clicking on the 'read more' button / link after displaying an excerpt

Comment: Based on the provided URL above the post is actually being served from `single.php` If you inspect the elements using browser dev tools, and hover around the `<body>` tag there's a bunch of classes applied and two of those are `single` and `single-post` that means it is using the `single.php`

Comment: you are correct Den _ it is single _ I added a `<span>` 'THIS IS SINGLE' and it is displayed

Comment: Template files aren't directly accessible via URL; i.e. `front-page.php`, `page.php`, `single.php`. Even though you're seeing `index.php` on the URL that doesn't mean it is using `index.php` template file -- it could be the other templates. It is how WP handles URL rewrites. If you don't want to see the `index.php` on the URL and want a clean and readable one go to *Appearance > Permalinks > Common Settings* and from there select the desired permalink structure.